# Can users leave comments on the android marketplace without having installed the latest version?

Tags: android, version, google-play

Can people comment on android applications on the marketplace if they dont have the latest version downloaded and installed on their device?

Just wondering for the senario where a user gets annoyed at your application for crashes or bugs that were present in say 1.0, but are fixed in 1.1, yet the user hasn't updated their app and comments with 1 star at how broken it still is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about Android Market, they can.

Try it yourself. Have an outdated app on your phone and rate it. It just works normally. There is no rating on a per-version basis. Open developer console and you'll see.

Comment: Btw, this is a question for Superuser, not StackOverflow, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

Comment: I'll remember to put these kinds of questions in superuser from now on.

Comment: No problem, I'm just saying because I've been bugged by others a lot about this, too... hope you aren't. :-)